# press home or back music stops

Tags: android, media-player

Hi In My Application I am playing one audio if i click back or home button that window should stop i am new to android please help me

```
final MediaPlayer mp = new MediaPlayer();
button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View arg0) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    Intent nextScreen = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Demovote2.class);
                    startActivity(nextScreen);
                    mp.start();
                    finish();

                }
            });



    }
```

Comment: can you see my answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should stop it on onpause method and replay it on onresume,

```
 @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        mp.stop();
        super.onPause();
    }

@Override
public void onResume(){

    // put your code here...
    mp.start();
     super.onPause();
}
```